# How can I initiate watch mode with ngc?

Tags: angular, angular-compiler, angular-aot

I would like to do the same, as I could in the good old `tsc` times: simply calling a `tsc -w`, and in the case of a changed file, it will be on the fly recompilated.

Unfortunately, `ngc` doesn't even seem to react anything to the `-w` flag, and even its possible command line arguments are completely undocumented.

But, `ng build` *has* a `--watch` flag, while it can create also AOT builds. Thus, probably a watch-mode `ngc` is possible.

But how?

Comment: I believe AOT compiler (ngc) doesn't support watch mode yet

Comment: @Maximus Ok, but why angular-cli still supports it, while it supports also aot?

Comment: I don't know. The recent talk I watched by Tobias about future plans included supporting watch mode for `ngc`, hence it doesn't support it now

Comment: @Maximus Could you please insert a link to this talk as an answer converted from your comment? I would be happy to upvote/accept it. Thanks!

Comment: sure, done, thanks. I've recently written [an article](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) that touches upon a compiler a bit. Might be of interest to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changelog of Angular 5 states that ngc watch is now a thing!
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-pentagonal-donut-2017-11-01

`Features: compiler-cli: add watch mode to ngc (#18818) (06d01b2)`

Comment: This answer is valid only from angular5. Until angular4, see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Version 5:

You can now use watch mode like this:

```
ngc -w
```

See [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12867#issuecomment-334229517) by Tobias:

> The command line ngc also has a -w option now that watches the file
>   system and we see speedups for subsequent builds of up to 10x, as we
>   have some logic in place to only compile components in node_modules
>   1x.

#### Version prior to 4

At the moment `ngc` doesn't support watch mode. It's addition identified by the Tobias Bosch as priority features. [Here is the video](https://youtu.be/RXYjPYkFwy4?t=16m30s) where he talks about that.

Comment: This answer is valid until Angular4. From Angular5, see the other answer.

Comment: @peterh, there was no need to undo an accept, I could have just updated the answer. I have, anyways